# Convert SQL to HQL for NOW()

Tags: sql, hql

Please help in converting below sql query to hql

```
 SELECT * FROM INVOICE WHERE INVOICE_DATE > NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

System throwing error for **NOW()**

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use parameters for IQuery

You should do something like

```
var q = nhSession.CreateQuery("FROM INVOICE WHERE INVOICE_DATE > :date");
q.SetParameter("date", DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7));
q.List...
```

EDIT

If your application server (C# app) is different from the SQL Server and they have different timezones then you can do:

1. Use UTC and keep the code above
2. Use straight TSql (for getdate() function) in ISqlQuery